# Redirect user after editing a post with the WordPress Front-end Editor plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to redirect the user after they've edited a post using the WordPress Front-end Editor plugin:

Plugin repository
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-front-end-editor/

GitHub
https://github.com/avryl/wp-front-end-editor

I thought about using the `save_post` hook:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

```
function redirect_after_edit(){
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'redirect_after_edit' );
```

Although this redirect works when editing a post via the back-end, it doesn't work when using WordPress Front-end Editor to edit a post.

Any idea how I can redirect the user after they've successfully edited a post using WordPress Front-end Editor?

Comment: `save_post` is called when editing from the front end editor. There's something else going on here. Are the headers already sent at this point? if so, then you can't perform a `header()` call in php. turn on the error reporting.

Comment: I notice there is no page refresh on submitting an edit. Could AJAX have some role in this?

Comment: No. because your plugin registered with WP AJAX and that data is sent to a controller function that then calls `do_($action, $arg1, $arg2)` and performs the `get/save` based on the data that that was received form the ajax object.

Comment: Right. In that case I can't understand why save_post isn't firing the redirect? Got Firebug on and no errors seem to be thrown.

Comment: As i advised you previously, you can't perform a `header redirect` if the headers have already been sent. Go to your `wp-config` file, then find `WP_DEBUG` and set it to `true`, then reload the page. If you get, "warning: headers already sent`, then you have identified your problem.

Comment: I've already got debug notices on and didn't get the message "headers already sent". The edit is allowed happen. But no redirect. I'm baffled? I could understand it if some output has already been sent, but it seems as though it hasn't (hence no debug notices displaying)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

… Since the plugin uses AJAX to update the post, redirecting the page on save_post will only alter the response. Take a look at the XHRs. It will have the page's HTML. Use redirect_post_location to redirect after saving.